# IIS LocalSystem only will run my exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

**IIS on WindowsServer  2012, ASP.NET MVC**

It is very bad to run an IIS 8.5 site as LocalSystem, but that is the only way I can get this exe to run. I need to be able to have the site run this:

```
                var pdfProcess = new Process();
                pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName =  SomeExeInProgramFiles;
                pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = stuff;
                pdfProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = docPath; //!!!!This is really important!!!!!
                pdfProcess.Start();
```

Running windows 2012, how can I let my AppPoolIdentity site run the above exe (only) from Program Files?

I have granted full control to the folder holding the exe to IIS APPPOOL\my pool name as a test, but still it won't run. Only if I set the app pool to run under LocalSystem (yicks)

Note: The EXE is a tool that needs to run to do tasks. We have no other option than to run it on request from the web site. We didn't write or have access to the exe.

Comment: Please expand on "won't run". Exactly what are the symptoms (including error messages). Perhaps you could use process monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to identify the security that you need.

Comment: Running the process monitor indicates no errors, and there are no errors returned when calling the exe in progress. It just doesn't do anything. Task Manager doesn't show the exe either. Only when I switch to LcoalSystem does the exe run and appear in Task Manager.

Comment: Did you check windows event logs and IIS logs?

Comment: Nothing in the IIS or EventVwr. When the exe is called, it just vaporizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `Load User Profile = True` in the `Application Pools` `Advanced Settings`.

Then I think you should be able to execute the process using the `ApplictionPoolIdentity`, so you can avoid using the LocalSystem account.

[image: Load User Profile in the Application Pools Advanced Settings dialog.]

Comment: This is true by default. If it is false, the site can't run as it can't read the registry :(

Comment: Ok. But you should get an exception if there was some security problems while trying to start the process. I would try to attach the Visual Studion debugger to the IIS process and take a closer look at that Exception, that might give you some clues.

Comment: Also have you looked into Impersonation ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(v=vs.100).aspx. I remember one similar case when I needed my app.pool process to start another process where I ended up having to create a local user with low privileges, that I used as Identity for the app.pool. It might be better than your current solution - to run it as LocalSystem.