# PDF Generation Works on Local Host but not on Web Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, deployment, stack-trace, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to generate pdf of my Razor View. It works fine on my local machine, but when I publish my site to web host and try to generate pdf I got the following error:

**Controller Action Method**

```
 //Generate and output the View pdf file
        public ActionResult PDFCatalogue(int id)
        {
            var productList = db.ProductImages.Include("Products")
                          .Select(m => new ProductDisplayViewModel
                          {
                              ProductId = m.Id,
                              Name = m.Products.Name,
                              ImageUrl = m.URL,
                              Thumbnail = m.URL.Replace(".jpg", "-thumb.jpg"),
                              CategoryId = m.Products.CategoryId,
                              CategoryName = m.Products.Category.CategoryName,
                              Sizes=m.Products.Sizes
                          }).Where(i => i.CategoryId == id).OrderByDescending(m => m.ProductId).ToList();

            TempData["CategoryName"] = db.Category.Where(m => m.Id == id).Select(k => k.CategoryName).SingleOrDefault();
            if (productList == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View("~/Views/Catalogue/PDFCatalogue.cshtml", productList);
            //return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(productList, "~/Views/Catalogue/PDFCatalogue.cshtml");
            //return new MvcRazorToPdf.PdfActionResult("~/Views/Catalogue/PDFCatalogue.cshtml", productList);
        }

        public ActionResult GeneratePDF(int id=0)
        {
            return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PDFCatalogue", new { id = id });
        }
```

**Server Error in '/' Application.**
    Unhandled Execution Error
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Exception:

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Exception]
   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html) +975
   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches) +50
   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context) +96
   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context) +250
   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651796
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

P.S: Rotativa make a directory `Rotativa` in root of the application, where it puts `wkhtmltopdf.exe` I also have set the permission of `Rotativa` directory to full control for application pool users as well

Comment: It sure sounds like permission issue.  How about this answer, to configure IIS?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823149/iis-localsystem-only-will-run-my-exe

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue and found [this](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/23) post which down the page says to swap out the .exe file on your production server with the one in the link below. This fixed the issue for me

Here is the download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzI_u_O3vUM1aEppb3ZVZXNsc28/view